# JUnit Test with EJB 3 and glassfish using java:module scoped resources

Tags: java, junit, glassfish, ejb, persistence

I am trying to get my JUnit test running which uses stateless EJBs from the same and different project and persistence (using a jta-data-source).

When using the following configuration, Glassfish wants me to use java:module scope instead of java:app scope in the glassfish-resource.xml(s).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">

<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool name="java:app/jdbc/test_pool"
        res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
        pool-resize-quantity="1" max-pool-size="5" steady-pool-size="0"
        statement-timeout-in-seconds="30">
        <property name="User" value="abc"></property>
        <property name="DatabaseName" value="test_db"></property>
        <property name="Password" value="abc"></property>
        <property name="ServerName" value="192.168.100.1"></property>
        <property name="Ssl" value="false"></property>
        <property name="TcpKeepAlive" value="false"></property>
        <property name="SocketTimeout" value="0"></property>
        <property name="PortNumber" value="1234"></property>
        <property name="LoginTimeout" value="0"></property>
        <property name="PrepareThreshold" value="5"></property>
        <property name="UnknownLength" value="2147483647"></property>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="java:app/jdbc/test_pool"
        jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/test"></jdbc-resource>
</resources>
```

The Error forcing me to use java:module scope:

```
INFORMATION: [EJBContainerImpl] Deploying as a File
Aug 22, 2014 2:15:33 PM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while deploying the app [ejb-app]
Aug 22, 2014 2:15:33 PM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle deploy
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Failue while processing glassfish-resources.xml(s) in the archive  -- Resource [ java:app/jdbc/test_pool ] is not allowed to specify the scope [ java:app/ ]. Acceptable scope for this resource is [ java:module/ ]
    at org.glassfish.resources.admin.cli.ResourcesXMLParser.getScopedName(ResourcesXMLParser.java:529)
    at org.glassfish.resources.admin.cli.ResourcesXMLParser.generateJDBCConnectionPoolResource(ResourcesXMLParser.java:708)
    at org.glassfish.resources.admin.cli.ResourcesXMLParser.generateResourceObjects(ResourcesXMLParser.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.resources.admin.cli.ResourcesXMLParser.<init>(ResourcesXMLParser.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.resources.module.ResourcesDeployer.processArchive(ResourcesDeployer.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.resources.module.ResourcesDeployer.processResources(ResourcesDeployer.java:766)
    at org.glassfish.resources.module.ResourcesDeployer.event(ResourcesDeployer.java:715)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:416)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerImpl.deploy(EJBContainerImpl.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:134)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:127)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at de.prototype.impl.prototype.crud.TestJavaEE.setUpClass(TestJavaEE.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Aug 22, 2014 2:15:33 PM org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand execute
```

After changing the scope to java:modue:

```
...
<jdbc-connection-pool name="java:module/jdbc/test_pool"
...
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="java:module/jdbc/test_pool"
        jndi-name="java:module/jdbc/test"></jdbc-resource>
...
```

I recieve the following Exception(s):

```
Aug 22, 2014 2:22:35 PM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
Aug 22, 2014 2:22:35 PM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer prepare method
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/test__pm
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:180)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:922)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:431)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerImpl.deploy(EJBContainerImpl.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:134)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:127)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at de.prototype.impl.prototype.crud.TestJavaEE.setUpClass(TestJavaEE.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/test__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:922)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:150)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:239)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:150)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/test__pm
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
    ... 55 more
```

Here is also the persistence.xml using the glassfish resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="test_pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:module/jdbc/test</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I found that the module scope on client side is different then the app scope (if i understand it right):
https://blogs.oracle.com/JagadishPrasath/entry/applying_scope_for_jdbc_resources

**But how is it possible to use a JUnit test with persisting, using the glassfish-resource.xml???**

If i comment the persistence-unit block out, the JUnit tests which are not persisting are working. I also can not use java:app scope, because then glassfish wants me to use java:module scope.

Here is the rest of the code (the "testAddPerson()" JUnit test will not work with persistence):

```
public class TestJavaEE {

    private static EJBContainer ejbContainer;
    private static Context ctx;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws NamingException {
        ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
        System.out.println("Starting the container");
        ctx = ejbContainer.getContext();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws NamingException {
        ejbContainer.close();
        System.out.println("Closing the container");
    }

    protected Object lookup(String name) throws NamingException {
        return ctx.lookup(name);
    }
}

public class PersonLogicBean2Test extends TestJavaEE {

    @EJB
    private PersonLogic2 personLogic2;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //personLogic2 = (PersonLogic2) lookup("java:global/classes/PersonLogicBean2");
        personLogic2 = (PersonLogic2) lookup("java:global/ejb-app/classesejb/PersonLogicBean2");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetPersonInfo() throws NamingException {
        String result = personLogic2.getPersonInfo("xx");
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        Assert.assertEquals("PersonLogicBean2xx", result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddPerson() throws NamingException {
        int cnt = personLogic2.getPersonCount();
        System.out.println("Count before: " + cnt);
        personLogic2.addPerson("jo");
        int result = personLogic2.getPersonCount();
        System.out.println("Count after: " + result);
        Assert.assertEquals(cnt + 1, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() throws NamingException {
        Assert.assertEquals(5, personLogic2.add(2, 3));
    }
}

@Stateless(mappedName="PersonLogicBean2")
public class PersonLogicBean2 implements PersonLogic2 {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonLogicBean2.class);

    @EJB
    private EmployeeCrudBean emplyeeCrud;

    @EJB
    private CalculatorBeanRemote calculatorBean;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "it works";
    }

    @Override
    public int getPersonCount() {
        return emplyeeCrud.getAllEmployees().size();
    }

    @Override
    public void addPerson(String name) {
        emplyeeCrud.addEmployee(new String[] { name });
    }

    @Override
    public String getPersonInfo(String person) {
        logger.info("Called getPersonInfo {}", person);
        return "PersonLogicBean2" + person;
    }

    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        //return a + b;
        return calculatorBean.add(a, b);
    }

    @Override
    public int subtract(int a, int b) {
        //return a - b;
        return calculatorBean.add(a, b);
    }
}

@Stateless(mappedName="EmployeeCrudBean")
public class EmployeeCrudBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void addEmployee(String[] names) {
        for (String name : names) {
            Employee e = new Employee();
            e.setName(name);
            em.persist(e);
        }
    }

    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Employee> query = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
        Root<Employee> root = query.from(Employee.class);

        query.select(root);
        query.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("id")));

        List<Employee> ret = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after losing lot's of time I got it right. I now can run my tests with my connection pool.
This problem is resulted by series of small maven code generation bugs in Netbeans.

I believe your particular problem is either the glassfish-resource.xml not being read by the embedded glassfish(look step 3 bellow) or you're not declaring dependency for the DB connectior(mysql or whatever youre using) inside the embedded glassfish plugin in your pom.xml(take a look in the pom.xml in step 1)

Bellow are a serie of steps for you to check

1 - Your pom.xml must have the path , plugin and dependencies configured for glassfish-embedded-static-shell,  as follow:

- Add in the properties at the top of your pom the path to your glassfish instalation folder(here is mine):

`<properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar>C:/Program Files/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/lib/embedded/glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar</glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar>
  </properties>`

- Add/check the plugin definition bellow(substitute mysql per maven in your case):
          `

  ```
  <build>
  ...
    <plugins>
      ...
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.0</version>

          <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.glassfish.main.common</groupId>
                  <artifactId>simple-glassfish-api</artifactId>
                  <version>4.1</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                  <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-static-shell</artifactId>
                  <version>4.1</version>
                  <scope>system</scope>
                  <systemPath>${glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar}</systemPath>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                  <version>5.1.28</version>
              </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
              <app>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</app>
              <port>8282</port>
              <contextRoot>${project.artifactId}</contextRoot>
              <foo>bar</foo>
          </configuration>

      </plugin>
    ...
    </plugins>
   ...
  </build>
  ```

`

2 - Your glassfish-resources... it's silly, but the jndi-name of your jdbc resource must have the prefix java:app/ so, add it as sample bellow(just the resource, the connection pool can have any name):
 
*Just remembering the name of your jdbc-resource in glassfish will not have the prefix java:app, e.g.: my jdbc-resource in glassfish is just ShrewdPCPool

3 - Third and the silliest, when deploying the embedded glassfish, the auto generated script of Netbeans doen't include /src/main/resources/setup in the class path, so, the simple solution is to make a copy of your glassfish-resources.xml para /src/main/resources/META-INF/ or if you are patient enough change the script.

Dont forget to clean, and after build with dependencies before you run your tests!

Comment: I am using ANT to build and postgresql as DB. ("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource") It did not work at all as excpected so I set up copy of a real glassfish instead of using the embedded. I start, stop and deploy all needed parts in a base class for  glassfish junit testing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with glassfish 4.1 embedded.
If you have a own library in your classpath. This lib has a java class that has annotation `@Stateless`. Then you get the exception. Try to put all your beans in your ejb-project.

Example:
common-project
entity-project
ejb-project
web-project

common-project is a normal java-project that contains:
Utils.java
`@Stateless   //<- Here is the problem<br>
class Utils {...}`